# Slant on divs from css border?

Tags: python, html, css, django

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px; text-align: center; padding: 0px;">
    {% for name in client_name %}
        <div class="appointment_data_div">{{ name }}<div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

css:

```
.appointment_data_div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0 #cccccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

For some reason, as you can see below, the divs are slanted?? I'm using django as my framework.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean/expect by "slant" ?  border-radius is here applied allright.

Comment: the divs are nested and as such will create the offset to the right from the border-thickness of the parent element.

Comment: Could you show me how to fix this? @tacoshy

Comment: `margin-left: -border thickness apply a negative `margin-left` equal to the border thickness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix end div ?

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px; text-align: center; padding: 0px;">
  {% for name in client_name %}
  <div class="appointment_data_div">{{ name }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your div's are nested, you can use this:

```
// in your css
div .appointment_data_div {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```